# Journey Builder Decision Split Using DE question

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder, design-attributes

We have a journey using Salesforce Campaign Member object as the entry source. Some of the contacts entering the journey (based on the member status on entry) goes through a decision split after waiting for specific number of days. The decision split looks up the member status from a DE, which is populated from Salesforce on a daily basis. The DE is added as an attribute in the Contact builder linking on email address. However, the decision split criteria is not able to pick up member status from the DE because the contact does not have a record in the All Subscriber list. This is because at this time no email has been sent to the contact from the journey, which will add the contact to the all subscriber list. How do I look up data from a DE, when the contact is not in the all subscriber list? Is there a work around for this? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way you linked in data designer on [email address](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Limitations-of-linking-a-Data-Extension-in-Data-Designer-on-Email-Address&language=en_US). To solve for your issue you should be linking to subscriberkey/contactkey (which is the SFDC contactID field)